# OpenLayers send GET request onSelect for feature image, kills performance

Tags: openlayers

My code works perfectly fine, except for the fact that everytime I click/hover over the "marker", openLayer tries to retrieve some image (.png) from my localserver. This is my code, and the image is not specified directly. Im not sure what to overwrite to forbid this behavior:

This is the error I get "onSelect":

```
GET http://localhost:8888/img/cloud-popup-relative.png 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my code. I hope someone can help, because the repeated GET request kill the performance!

```
var lonlat = convertProjectionToSphere(location);
    console.log(lonlat);
    var pointFeatures = [];

    var pointGeometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat);
    var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        pointGeometry,
        null,
        {
            pointRadius: 16,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            externalGraphic:'img/mapIcons/Multi-Wave-test.png'
        });
    pointFeatures.push(pointFeature);

    // Add features to the layer
    var pointLayer = map.getLayer('Vectors');
    pointLayer.addFeatures(pointFeatures);

    // Add select feature control required to trigger events on the vector layer.
    var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(pointLayer, {
        hover: true,
        onSelect: function(feature) { // last point in my code from the stack trace
            var layer = feature.layer;
            feature.style.fillOpacity = 1;
            feature.style.pointRadius = 20;
            //layer.drawFeature(feature);
            var content =   '<div style="background-color:white;"><strong>Feature:</strong>'+
                            '<br/>' + feature.id +
                            '<br/><br/><strong>Location:</strong>'+
                            '<br/>' + feature.geometry +'</div>';
            var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                            feature.id+"_popup",
                            feature.geometry.getBounds().
                            getCenterLonLat(),
                            new OpenLayers.Size(250, 100),
                            content,
                            null,   // anchor
                            true,   // closeBox exists
                            null); //closeBoxCallback
            feature.popup = popup;
            map.addPopup(popup);
        },
        onUnselect: function(feature) {
            var layer = feature.layer;
            feature.style.fillOpacity = 1;
            feature.style.pointRadius = 16;
            feature.renderIntent = null;
            layer.drawFeature(feature);
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
        }
    });
    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a "[FramedCloud](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup/FramedCloud-js.html)" popup. The image that OpenLayers wants to load is the boarder of that popup. The image is contained in the "img" Folder that comes with the OpenLayers-distribution.
You can change the path to the images folder via OpenLayers.ImgPath. Here is a [link](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers-js.html#OpenLayers.ImgPath).
Alternativly you may use a simpler popup style like Anchored. I think it does not use an image as its frame.